# does overwriting a built-in command cost me too much speed in the long run?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was searching for overwriting a built-in command and found a way by defining a function in `~/.bashrc` file. I want to overwrite the `cd` command so that when I change to a new directory, it will do the following:

- activate virtualenv in for python if available.
- print out the lines in a file called ".todo" if available.
- Possible new options...

I'm going to use it only for development and actually I can do these tasks by writing one more command e.g. `$ cat .todo`.

**The question is:** Does overwriting the cd command will cause me low speed when using other applications(which use the cd command in a script) or is it negligible* ?

*Of course it will cause a decrease in speed as it will check for two if conditions every time but is this decrease negligible?

I'm using a laptop not an embedded system, so I have sufficient processing power.

Comment: "overwrite" how exactly? in most cases, non-interactive shells won't source your `~/.bashrc` - see for example [Why does bashrc check whether the current shell is interactive?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257571/why-does-bashrc-check-whether-the-current-shell-is-interactive)

Comment: @steeldriver I tried this and this is correct. non-interactive shells do not source `~/.bashrc` and work with builtin commands. I will accept this comment as an answer if stated that way.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer: Try it. Prepare by being ready to undo the change.

I use:

At the very beginning of my `~/.bash_aliases` (sourced from `~/.bashrc`):

```
declare -i is_interactive
case $- in
  *i*) is_interactive=1 ;;
  *) is_interactive=0;;
esac
```

And, later,

```
if [[ $is_interactive -eq 1 ]] ; then
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

On all my systems, by reflex, (5x Desktops, 4x Laptops), some old, and I've never noticed any time lag. YMMV, depending on how much work you do before and after the real `cd`.